# Open link in browser or open app

Tags: iphone, url, iframe

I have made an iphone app. The app calls the webpage and displays the content. Server side coding is in php. The problem is I have several links in the webpage. When I click on the link in the webpage it opens the entire page and I am no longer able to go back to where I was.

I tried iframe but not all the website support it like google, facebook. What I am looking is someway to open the link in browser or launch the another app, like the app of facebook. I have quite thoroughly searched for the solution without much luck.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to give this a read: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

Answer (score 0):

To implement navigation for UIWebView you can do the following: create two buttons, one for going forward in history and one for going back. And here is the code for that buttons you must include:

```
//For going forward
if (yourWebView.canGoForward)
{
   yourWebView.goForward();
}

//For going back
if (yourWebView.canGoBack)
{
   yourWebView.goBack();
}
```